# Is there any way to improve my quesiton?

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes my question gets downvoted, but the downvoter doesn't leave a comment ( as it's not necessary).
Is there any way to improve my question under such circumstances?

Comment: Most of DS SE users leave a helpful comment if they find a qn off-topic. :)  Having said that, maybe go through this help [doc](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help) before framing a question.  And, Sean put is quite clearly and hope you found it helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one question by you here: [Need some help on data mining platform recommendation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16984/need-some-help-on-data-mining-platform-recommendation)

I don't know who downvoted or why, but I agree it should be improved. You are asking for a tools recommendation, which is not really on-topic. The requirements are only partly data-science-related.

More importantly, you don't give any indication that you've tried to answer the question yourself. If you have, then you didn't say why obvious solutions don't fit, leaving it to people to guess at why you're not using X or Y already.

Ask specific questions that show you've ruled out obvious answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did have some research, but as I'm Chinese, most of tools I've investigated were Chinese software except for Weka & SPSS, so I omitted my research in the question. These informations will be added.